# Using charindex to correct name with two commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL Query that updates a field with a proper version of their name. Currently, we store employees as Last Name, First Name, and will be implementing email variables so we can say "Hello First Name Last Name"

I currently have a working query that corrects where there is a single comma, but I need a query that works the same way, but when their are two commas such as "Doe, Jr, John"  to appear as "John Doe, Jr"

```
UPDATE A_EMPLOYEE SET DISPLAY_NAME = CONCAT((SUBSTRING(
    LAST_NAME,
    CHARINDEX (', ', LAST_NAME) + 2,
    LEN (LAST_NAME)
)),' ',(SUBSTRING(
    LAST_NAME,
    0,
    CHARINDEX (', ', LAST_NAME, 0)
))) WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = @var (variable set by system)
```

Comment: The proper thing would be to not store first and last name in the same field. However, I am guess that is beyond your control. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be messy, so you will need lots of test samples, but here you go. Use `REVERSE()` to find the last comma, then use that location to parse the first and last.

```
--DECLARE @fullname VARCHAR(100) = 'Doe, Jr, John'
--DECLARE @fullname VARCHAR(100) = 'Smith, Mike'
DECLARE @fullname VARCHAR(100) = 'Johnson, Sr, John'


SELECT @fullname AS raw_name, 
LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@fullname, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@fullname), 0)-1))) AS first_name, 
LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@fullname, LEN(@fullname)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@fullname), 0)))) AS last_name, 
LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@fullname, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@fullname), 0)-1))) + ' ' + 
LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@fullname, LEN(@fullname)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@fullname), 0)))) AS full_name
```

Comment: This is the solution I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach that may do the heavy lifting.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (FullName varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('Doe, Jr, John')
,('Doe, John')
,('John Doe')


Select A.*
      ,NewValue = case when Pos2 is Null then Pos1 else
                  case when Pos3 is Null then concat(Pos2,' ',Pos1) else
                  case when pos4 is null then concat(Pos3,' ',Pos1,' ',Pos2)
                  end end end
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
              Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')))
                    ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')))
                    ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')))
                    ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')))
                    ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)')))
              From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(FullName,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
FullName        NewValue
Doe, Jr, John   John Doe Jr
Doe, John       John Doe
John Doe        John Doe
```